# Spark SQL 'Show table extended from db like table gives different result' from Hive

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
spark.sql("SHOW TABLE EXTENDED IN DB LIKE 'TABLE'")

Beeline >>SHOW TABLE EXTENDED IN DB LIKE 'TABLE';
```

Both queries have different results.

If I run the same query in Spark it is giving different result than Hive. Format and `lastUpdatedTime` is missing in `Spark SQL`.

If anyone have idea then please let me know how to see `lastUpdatedTime` of Hive table from Spark SQL

Comment: "Both queries have different results." - can you post the different results here. clarity in question is very imp...

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
scala> val df = spark.sql(s"describe extended ${db}.${table_name}").select("data_type").where("col_name == 'Table Properties'")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [data_type: string]

scala> df.map(r => r.getString(0).split(",")(1).trim).collect
res39: Array[String] = Array(last_modified_time=1539848078)

scala> df.map(r => r.getString(0).split(",")(1).trim.split("=")(1)).collect.mkString
res41: String = 1539848078
```

Comment: can you pls write free text alog with code so that new comers will understand the context ?

Comment: last_modified_time is when last time DDL have updated/altered . But,lastUpdatedTime from hive shows when table have recent inserts or DML has been done . Interestingly , it is coming in Hive/Beeline but in Spark SQL